# How to get registered actions from UnityEngine.UIElements.TextField & Button

Tags: c#, unit-testing, unity-game-engine, unity-editor, unity3d-editor

I am creating automated unit tests in Unity, and want to test if a method used
`TextField.RegisterValueChangedCallback(SomeMethod);`
with a specific method. I also want to test if a UIElement Button has a specific method registered with: `Button.clicked += SomeMethod;`.

**My question:** Is there a way to access all registered methods from these text fields and buttons? Or maybe a (not too messy) work around?

I am `using UnityEngine.UIElements;` in my project.

*Simple version of what method I want to test*:

```
VisualTreeAsset root; // Assigned in some other method

public void TestedMethod(){
    // Get the field from the VisualTreeAsset root
    textField = root.Q<TextField>("FieldName");

    // Register
    // This is the line I want to be tested:
    textField.RegisterValueChangedCallback(SomeMethod);
}
```

*Pseudo code to illustrate what I want to test:*

```
[Test]
public void SomeTest()
{
    // Get references from wherever they may be...
    Action SomeMethod = [...];
    TextField textField = [...];
    Button button = [...];

    // Assertions
    // This is the part I need help with:
    Assert.IsTrue( textField.GetRegisteredValueChange().Contains(SomeMethod) );
    Assert.IsTrue( button.clicked.Contains(SomeMethod) );
}
```

I have looked through the Unity API, and can't find anything that seems usefull:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UIElements.TextField.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UIElements.Button.html

Comment: You are not suppose to test whether a method from Unity engine works or not. In this situation, you have to go with the fact it does because Unity did the testing for you. You would test your own code implementation, testing other framework functioning is irrelevant because if it did not, you would not be able to fix it anyway.

Comment: @Everts. The reason I want to test this, is so I can check if my own code ever registers/subscribes.

Comment: In this case, you could create a register/unregister method from an interface, then check that the mocked object gets its method called.

Answer (score 0):

You might use UnityEngine.EventSystems
[unityengine.eventsystems](/questions/tagged/unityengine.eventsystems)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I now know where I can continue researching. However, it would help a lot if you could add a little more information on how to solve this :)

Comment: @Bjørn-Sigurd you can check answer here for button click event. Also there should be similar solution for text value change.    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71308946/i-want-the-player-to-move-while-the-key-is-pressed-unity-c-sharp/71309097?noredirect=1#comment126046412_71309097