# I want the "player" to move while the key is pressed Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

how to make the "player" to move while the key is pressed and held?
I have a button in the GUI

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class moveLeft : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;

    public void Start(){
        player.transform.position = new Vector3 
        (player.position.x-1, player.position.y, player.position.z);
    }
}
```

Comment: which key? Move how? => [`Input.GetKey`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html) and [`Time.deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html)

Comment: There is a lot of information out there but this code does not show any movement or key presses.   Except at the time this move left script starts it moves a player 1 unit left. And stops and is done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow) means you hold left arrow key in keybord.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class moveLeft : MonoBehaviour
{
public Transform player;

[SerializableField] float speed;

void Update(){
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        player.transform.position += Vector3.left * speed * Time.deltaTime;
}
}
```

Edit:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class moveLeft : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{
public Transform player;

[SerializableField] float speed;

void Update(){
    if(isActive)
        player.transform.position += Vector3.left * speed * Time.deltaTime;
}

bool isActive = false;
public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    isActive = true;
}

public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    isActive = false;
}

}
```

Comment: I have a button in the GUI, sorry I forgot to clarify

Comment: @Ilya So, you want to move it while you press the button right?

Comment: Yes⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Comment: @Ilya I editted.